# SQL Over_rumber on group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

This is my output.

```
Prod_ Order No_  | Old Item No_ | Quantity | Control Date
     2001            KR2000001      20          2016-08-22
     2001            KR2000001      20          2016-08-22
     2001            KR2000001      20          2016-08-22
     2001            KR2000001      20          2016-08-22
     3001            KR3000001      25          2016-08-22
     3001            KR3000001      25          2016-08-22
```

This my sql.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Prod_ Order No_] ORDER BY [Prod_ Order No_] DESC) AS rn,
                main.[Prod_ Order No_], items.[Old Item No_], main.[Item No_], main.Quantity, main.[Control Date] , main.[Control Rate],
                main.[Ok Red], main.[Defect Desc], main.[State And Solve], main.[Location Code], main.[Description],
                [Item Shipment Date], main.[Final Parti No_], main.[Produced By Users], main.[Renk]
            FROM [Zenon data$Final Quality Control]  AS main
            JOIN [Zenon data$Item] AS items ON items.No_= main.[Item No_]
            JOIN [Zenon data$Production Entry] AS pe ON pe.[Prod_ Order No] = main.[Prod_ Order No_]            
    ) AS ax
WHERE rn > 0 AND rn < =20
```

I want to this output, but i couldn't.

```
Prod_ Order No_  | Old Item No_ | Quantity | Control Date
     2001            KR2000001      20          2016-08-22
     3001            KR3000001      25          2016-08-22
```

my main table is Final Quality Control. Primary key => Prod Order No_

Comment: Why this condition `WHERE rn > 0 AND rn < =20` what happens when you use `WHERE rn=1` <-- this may get exact result

Comment: i want to get data 20 row from my database to android app. so i have to pagination.  i could do this. i want to prod_order_no be unique in output

Comment: you cant have pagination on your id and same time only one row for this id... Precise your ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select * from (
          SELECT ax.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Prod_ Order No_]  ORDER BY [Prod_ Order No_] DESC) AS rnpage,

          FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT  
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Prod_ Order No_] ORDER BY [Prod_ Order No_] DESC) AS rn,
                             main.[Prod_ Order No_], items.[Old Item No_], main.[Item No_], main.Quantity, main.[Control Date] , main.[Control Rate],
                             main.[Ok Red], main.[Defect Desc], main.[State And Solve], main.[Location Code], main.[Description],
                              [Item Shipment Date], main.[Final Parti No_], main.[Produced By Users], main.[Renk]
                                    FROM [Zenon data$Final Quality Control]  AS main
                                    JOIN [Zenon data$Item] AS items ON items.No_= main.[Item No_]
                                    JOIN [Zenon data$Production Entry] AS pe ON pe.[Prod_ Order No] = main.[Prod_ Order No_]

                    ) AS ax
          WHERE rn=1

  ) ax2 where rnpage between 1 and 20
```

Comment: i got it what did you do.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Prod_ Order No_] ORDER BY [Prod_ Order No_] DESC) AS rn,
    main.[Prod_ Order No_], items.[Old Item No_], main.[Item No_], main.Quantity, main.[Control Date] , main.[Control Rate],
    main.[Ok Red], main.[Defect Desc], main.[State And Solve], main.[Location Code], main.[Description],
    [Item Shipment Date], main.[Final Parti No_], main.[Produced By Users], main.[Renk]
    FROM [Zenon data$Final Quality Control]  AS main
    JOIN [Zenon data$Item] AS items ON items.No_= main.[Item No_]
    JOIN [Zenon data$Production Entry] AS pe ON pe.[Prod_ Order No] = main.[Prod_ Order No_]
) AS ax
WHERE rn > 0 AND rn < =20
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
```

Comment: Thanks for help. but it doesnt work, i am sorry for my english. i cant add group by.

Comment: Column 'ax.rn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Kayra Try  GROUP BY 1, 2, 4, 3

Answer (score 0):

For pagination use Offset and fetch. Just change the offset and fetch values with your pagination.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Prod_ Order No_] ORDER BY [Prod_ Order No_] DESC) AS rn,
main.[Prod_ Order No_], items.[Old Item No_], main.[Item No_], main.Quantity, main.[Control Date] , main.[Control Rate],
main.[Ok Red], main.[Defect Desc], main.[State And Solve], main.[Location Code], main.[Description],
[Item Shipment Date], main.[Final Parti No_], main.[Produced By Users], main.[Renk]
FROM [Zenon data$Final Quality Control]  AS main
JOIN [Zenon data$Item] AS items ON items.No_= main.[Item No_]
JOIN [Zenon data$Production Entry] AS pe ON pe.[Prod_ Order No] = main.[Prod_ Order No_]

) AS ax
ORDER BY rn
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: i cant do this. because rn is a dynamic.

Comment: it's pagination for me, rn can be 0, 20,40, 60 so i cant do that. thanks for help.